# Como debugar para saber qual procedure ou tabela estão sendo executados com Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou há 10 dias no novo trabalho, e estou tendo algumas dificuldades - o que é normal, dependendo da dificuldade.

Tenho uma Table dentro de um Repeater, que é alimentada por uma Procedure.

Como eu faço com o Debug, para encontrar a Procedure que está sendo executada através dessa linha?

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdTipoUsuario" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdTipoUsuario")%>' />
```

Esse é todo o repeater e a table:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGerenciaProcessos" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemCommand" 
    onitemdatabound="rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="gerenciaProcessos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Consultar processo</th>
            <th>Priorizar</th>
            <th>Priorizado</th>
            <th>Nº do processo</th>
            <th>Data de abertura</th>
            <th>Início da análise</th>
            <th>Término na análise</th>
            <th>Situação</th>
            <th>Grupo</th>
            <th>Cota</th>
            <th>Etapa</th>
            <th>Analista</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnConsultarProcessos" OnClick="btnConsultarProcessos_Click" runat="server" Text="Consultar processo" CommandName="ConsultaProcessoGestor" CssClass="acessos" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdProcesso" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdProcesso")%>'/>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdAnalise" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdAnalise")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdUsuario" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdUsuarioAn")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdWorkFlowItem" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdWorkFlowItem")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdTipoUsuario" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdTipoUsuario")%>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbPriorizar" runat="server" CssClass="clickPriorizar">Priorizar</asp:LinkButton>
                <!--<a href="#"class="clickPriorizar">Priorizar</a>-->
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="ckbPriorizado" <%# Eval("IcPriorizado")%> disabled></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CdProcesso")%>'      runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("DtCriacao")%>'       runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("DtInicio")%>'        runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("DtFim")%>'           runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("NmWorkFlowItem")%>'  runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CdGrupo")%>'         runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CdCota")%>'          runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoStatus")%>'    runat="server" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("NomeUsuario")%>'     runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

A dificuldade está em saber como eu debugo a linha `...Eval("Meu_Campo")...`

Answer (score 1):

O conteúdo dinâmico do Repeater é carregado normalmente do seguinte modo:

```
rptGerenciaProcessos.DataSource = RetornaDados(parametro1, parametro2);
rptGerenciaProcessos.DataBind();
```

Para saber qual Procedure é executada para alimentar o Repeater, você deve percorrer o caminho ao inverso do que está definido da atribuição do `DataSource`.

Pode ser que o caminho fique mais complicado se essa atribuição não está explícita no *code-behind* de sua página (normalmente [nome_pagina].aspx.cs). Ele pode estar chamando uma função genérica de outro lugar para carregar os dados:

```
CarregaRepeater(rptGerenciaProcessos, RetornaDados(parametro1, parametro2));
```

Eu aconselho, a procurar por `RetornaDados(parametro1, parametro2)`s no código fonte da página. Se não achar procure por todas as ocorrências do `rptGerenciaProcessos`. Use o "Find All".

**Sobre debugar o `Eval("Meu_Campo")`**:

Esse trecho de código define que o valor na coluna "Meu_Campo" irá nesse campo da sua página, pra cada item do DataSource. Você pode sobrescrever esse comportamento através do evento `OnItemDataBound`:

```
void rptGerenciaProcessos_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        Processo item = (Processo)e.Item.DataItem;
        // Coloque um breakpoint aqui e analise a variável "item"
        if (Item.CdTipoUsuario == 5) {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("hdfCdTipoUsuario")).Value = "50";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você cia um página sua_pagina.aspx é criado o CodeBehind dela com  nome_sua_pagina.cs é ai que esta sendo carregado seu repeater.
Edite esta página .cs e encontre rptGerenciaProcessos.DataSource nele estará o conteúdo dos dados.
Pode ser carregado por um objeto ou pela execução de método.
No método que estará o nome da SP ou expressão SQl usada para a carga.